# How I can use Zaitsev's rule backwards?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

In the reaction
$$\ce{H2O +CH3CH2CH=CHCH3->} ?$$
Which of the doubly bonded carbon atoms should I choose with the $\ce{OH-}$ ?

Comment: Zaitsev's rule in reverse is basically just Markonikoff's rule.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand a backwards Zaitsev's rule.

But one thing that I am sure about, is that you can decide that in which carbon which would $\ce{OH-}$ get attached by using Markovnikov's rule. This rule states that hydrogen would get attached to the double bonded carbon which has the greater number of hydrogen atoms attached to it, or conversely $\ce{OH-}$ or any other negative part would get attached to the double bonded carbon which has the lesser number of hydrogen atoms attached to it.